# Uncertainty powers

Tags: chemistry

In class, we are working with powers of uncertainties. The teacher, however, handed me an extremely technical article, and it makes very little sense. Could one please explain to me step by step how to solve this expression?

$$(1.234\pm0.001)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

I appreciate any help granted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to think of uncertainties in the following form:

If $$a=b\pm c$$ then

$a^n=b^n\pm{(\frac{cn}{b})|b^n|}$

Hope that helps.

Comment: Didn't you answer my other question?

Comment: @Apple Yeah, I did